# Can not run "npm run start"

Tags: python, reactjs, webpack, node-modules

there is a version conflict between the required version of webpack by react-scripts and the version that's currently installed in your project's dependencies.

I changed my react-scripts to "react-scripts": "^4.0.0", in my package.json and deleted nodemodules and installed it again but it still doesn't seem to work.

P.S. I'm a beginner progammer so i might be seriously messing something up.

Also I'm on a M1 Mac

The error:
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! eva-community-manager@1.0.0 start: `env-cmd -e default npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the eva-community-manager@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ehabkhan/.npm/_logs/2024-01-30T16_19_56_178Z-debug.log

Comment: It sounds like you used `create-react-app`, in which case: you want to stop using that. The project was discontinued and React no longer includes it in its ["create a new react app" documentation](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project). Just start a new project based on Next.js and you're pretty much good to go.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.